# Insert whitespace after delimiter with CSV writer

Tags: python, csv

```
f = open("file1.csv", "r")
g = open("file2.csv", "w")

a = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";", skipinitialspace=True)
b = csv.writer(g, delimiter=";")

for line in a:
    b.writerow(line)
```

In the above code, I try to load file1.csv using the `csv` module in Python2.7, and then write it in file2.csv using a `csv.writer`.

My issue comes from existing whitespaces (a single space character) after the delimiter in the input file. I need to remove them in order to do some data manipulation later on, so I used the `skipinitialspace=True` argument for the reader. However, I cannot get the writer to print the space char after the delimiter, and therefore disturbing any subsequent `diff`ing of the two files.

I tried to use the `Sniffer` class to auto-generate a `Dialect` but I guess my input files (coming from a large complex legacy system, with dozens of fields and poor quoting and escaping) are proving to be too complex for this.

In more simple terms I'm looking for the answers to the following questions:

- How can I insert a space character after each delimiter in the `writer`?
- Incidently, what are the reasons to prohibit the use of multi-character strings as delimiters? `delimiter="; "` would've solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `file` objects in proxies that add the whitespace:

```
>>> class DelimitedFile(file):
...     def write(self, value):
...             super(DelimitedFile, self).write(value.replace(";", "; "))
... 
>>> f = DelimitedFile("foo", "w")
>>> f.write("hello;world")
>>> f.close()
>>> open("foo").read()
'hello; world'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you left the whitespace you want written in (removing/restoring it during processing), or put it back after processing but before writing, that would take care of it.

Comment: Thank you, your second suggestion is exactly what I'm thinking about. I just fear that would add extra lines of code and wonder how *pythonic* this really is. I'd hate to find out that a simple option of the module could've saved me the hassle.

Comment: @rahmu From the Zen of Python: "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. Although practicality beats purity."

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write to a `StringIO` object, and then to replace the semicolons with `'; '`, or to do so during processing of the lines, if you do any other processing.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first, I would probably do something like this:

```
for k, line in enumerate(a):
    if k == 0:
        b.writerow(line)
    else:
        b.writerow(' ' + line) #assuming line is always a string, if not just use str() on it
```

As for the second, I have no idea.